# Which factors are most important in getting a high star rating?

Tags: luigis-mansion-dark-moon

Which variables are most important in getting a high star rating on a level in *Luigi's Mansion: Dark Moon*?

- Clear time
- Ghosts captured
- Health lost
- Treasure collected

Comment: I won't put this as an answer because I don't know for sure yet but I think it's all of them. I think there is a thresh hold and if you get all of your stats below that threshold you will get better rankings. This can be done on multiple runs too. I did one mission 3 times because I kept overlooking something. On the first run I didn't do anything well. On the second I got a ton of gold and only got 2 stars. On the third, I beat it in around 5 minutes taking no damage and I got 3 stars. So I don't believe you have to do everything in one run. This is just a theory though.

Comment: @Tony My personal suspicion is that it is time, damage, money.

Comment: The thresholds must really vary per level. In the 3rd boss fight I got 220 damage and I still got 3 stars.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your "score" is calculated by this formula:

```
Score = Ghosts * 120 + Coins - Time (seconds) - Damage * 6
```

Then, every level has a "score table", holding how much score one needs for how many stars (some levels have even negative scores to get three stars). The exact numbers are not fully known.

Source (with guessed scores): http://www.gamefaqs.com/3ds/632930-luigis-mansion-dark-moon/faqs/66895

```
Mission     3* Requirement
A-1         1000
A-2         1700 – 2000
A-3         500 – 800
A-4         1300 – 1400
A-5         900 – 1000
A-Boss      -200
A-Bonus     2100 – 2400
B-1         1100 – 1400
B-2         1800 – 2200
B-3         500 – 600
B-4         1500 – 2000
B-5         1400
B-Boss      -600 – -200
B-Bonus     1400 – 1500
C-1         1900 – 2000
C-2         2700 – 2800
C-3         1200 – 1400
C-4         200 – 500
C-5         2900 – 3400
C-Boss      2100 – 2500
C-Bonus     2000 – 2300
D-1         2200
D-2         1400 – 1500
D-3         1000 – 1300
D-Boss      -100
D-Bonus     2000 – 2100
E-1         1900 – 2300
E-2         2500 – 2900
E-3         800 – 1600
E-4         -200
E-5         6400 – 7000
E-Boss      -400 – -200
E-Bonus     2100 – 2600
F-1         -200
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if we will get a conclusive answer but here are some observations I have made.

One some levels I received a 3* rating with a large amount of health lost (over 150). So I think HP is a smaller factor.

One level I got 3* with only $5 collected so treasure doesn't seem to be a factor at all. That was a boss level so they could be different.

Capturing Boos does not count towards the rating - once you have caught a Boo in a level, when you replay that level it will not appear. (Plus on one level I got a 3* rating without capturing the Boo.)

I also tried repeating a level (A-3). The first time I got a 3* rating, the second time a 2* rating even though my time was faster and I lost less HP. However the second time I took a different route and didn't capture all the ghosts.

So think for 3* you need to at least capture *all possible ghosts*, and then do it in a quick time. Treasure and HP lost don't seem to make a difference.